# Is creating extensions for Microsoft Teams in NET Core supported?

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-teams

I did not manage to find in the documentation Microsoft Teams extension samples  that use .NET Core. Every sample I found in GitHub included those of Build 2019 are in .NET Framework. I was expected to see everything in .NET Core, especially for something like Microsoft Teams which is recent and moving fast.

So that makes me wonder if .NET Core is supported for building Microsoft Teams extension.

Comment: You could always check [apisof.net](https://apisof.net/) to see whether the APIs you need are available for .NET Core.

Comment: Interesting site thanks, I did not know about this one but it does not really help for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core was not supported for bots until Bot Framework SDK v4. It wasn't supported for Bot Framework 3.x. All of our samples that use bots, with one exception, still support Bot Framework 3.x, and we expect to support both 3.x and 4.x indefinitely: in part because there's no good way to migrate from 3.x to 4.x.

The exception is our [sample app for our Bot Framework 4.x SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet/tree/master/CSharp/Samples), which is currently in beta.

Over time we expect to focus more on .NET Core as we add Bot Framework SDK 4.x support to more of our samples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the sample app. However I am not talking only about bots for teams, I am wondering about Teams extensions/apps in genera (with or without a bot). 

Is the .NET Core SDK to develop a Microsoft Teams extension/app in beta as well ? I have not been able to find a Visual Studio template to develop a Microsoft Teams app. There is the App Studio on Microsoft Teams that can generate some code to get started but it's in .NET Framework not .NET Core.

Comment: As told in Microsoft Teams community call, there is not yet any Visual Studio templates available. The samples provided by @Bill which use Bot Builder SDK v4 (currently in preview) are the best way to get started.